# How can I remove or substitute the default RSS2 template?

Tags: rss

I'm trying to add a customized RSS2 template but I cannot deactivate the current RSS2 feed. Removing the do_feed_rss2 action does not seem to work. I've copied feed-rss2.php to my theme folder and modified it. But I have had no success in removing the default RSS2 template.

```
remove_all_actions( 'do_feed_rss2' );
add_action( 'do_feed_rss2', function( $for_comments ) {
    if ( $for_comments )
        load_template( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed-rss2-comments.php' );
    else
    {
        if ( $rss_template = locate_template( 'feed-rss2.php' ) )
            // locate_template() returns path to file
            // if either the child theme or the parent theme have overridden the template
            load_template( $rss_template );
        else
            load_template( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed-rss2.php' );
    }
```

}, 10, 1 );

Any ideas?

Update: Finally I got no feeds to appear, but if comment this code out the feeds to not come back, even if I flush the rewrite rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a way to replace the default feed, 'feed', but I was able to add a new feed, 'rss-feed', and changed the links in the header to say the new feed was the default:

```
function my_rss_template() {
    add_feed( 'rss-feed', 'my_custom_rss_render' );
}

function my_custom_rss_render() {
    get_template_part( 'feed', 'rss-feed' );
}

add_action('init','my_rss_template');

function custom_rss($output, $show) {
    if (in_array($show, array('rss_url', 'rss2_url', 'rss', 'rss2', '')))
    $output = site_url() . '/rss-feed';
    return $output; 
}

add_filter('bloginfo_url', 'custom_rss', 10, 2);
add_filter('feed_link', 'custom_rss', 10, 2);
```

I copied the file feed-rss2.php from the wp-inlcudes folder to my theme folder, renamed it rss-feed.php and modified it for my needs. After this don't forget to update your permalinks in the dashboard Settings.